# admin page throws the error message after upgrade 2.1.2 to 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, setup-upgrade

I have upgrade my website using following steps

```
1- composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update
2- composer update
3- rm -rf var/di var/generation
4- php bin/magento cache:clean
5- php bin/magento cache:flush
6- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
7- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
8- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

All is done without any issues.

Front end website also working but my admin page was not working its throws following error

```
1 exception(s):Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::manage_search)
Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::manage_search)
#0 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))
#1 /home/example.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult', Array, Array)
#2 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php(146): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))
#3 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php(109): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu()
#4 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php(348): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu()
#5 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php(308): Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu()
#6 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php(21): Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl()
#7 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute()
#8 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#12 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#15 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/example.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#18 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#21 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#22 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'infortis_cgen_m...')
#25 /home/example.com/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/example.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#28 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /home/example.com/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#31 {main}
```

Please help any one. how to solve this issue.

Comment: Issue with `Smile_ElasticsuiteCore` module disable it & all works fine

Comment: i tried to disable that module from cli using following command `php bin/magento module:disable Smile_ElasticsuiteCore`
No modules were changed.

Comment: Means? Still getting error?

Comment: Yes its still getting error. and i open the `app/etc/config.php` file and its showing like below. `'Smile_ElasticsuiteCore' => 0,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog' => 0,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogRule' => 0,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogOptimizer' => 1,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteSwatches' => 0,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteThesaurus' => 0,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteTracker' => 0,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory' => 0,`

Comment: Issue is here `1 exception(s):Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::manage_search)` disable this `Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogOptimizer`. Upgrade, Compile, Index, Clear Cache & Check

Comment: Hi after disable that module its working fine. thanks for your assistance. and its any possible to clear that issue?

Comment: It's custom or purchased module? If purchased then contact provider

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here `1 exception(s):Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::manage_search)`

Disable all modules related to `Smile_` & check again